# While loop printing twice during one loop

Tags: c

So I have this little while loop which seems to print out my text twice during one run.

So here is the code:

```
int main(void){
 char cont;
 int check = 1;

 while(check == 1){
  printf("Something");
  cont = getchar();
  if(cont == 'j')
   check = 1;
  }
}
```

Now the output of this is:

Something, now it waits for input
Something, Something and waits for input.

After the first print,  it will print twice when I press j.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is stuck in loop because you test `check==1` and check is always 1
you can make else part

```
if(cont == 'j')
   check = 1;
else 
   check =0;
```

Answer (score 6):

You press 'j' and the 'newline', so you typed two chars and loop executes twice before starting to read next line.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, not sure why a down-vote.  Maybe add something about the buffered nature of `stdin`?

Answer (score 1):

It is an infinite loop. Always recheck your program.

Maybe you wanted

```
if(cont == 'j')
    check = 0;
```